# Can't run Julia in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter, apple-m1

Has anyone had a problem running julia from a jupyter notebook?

I have looked at how-to pages like [this one](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/installing-julia-using-on-jupyter-notebook-7177742db1cf) and [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-best-use-julia-with-jupyter-82678a482677), which all pretty much recommend the same series of steps:

1. Open the terminal, launch Julia, and `Pkg.add("IJulia")`.

I follow this step and got the following output

```
Resolving package versions...
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
  [7073ff75] + IJulia v1.23.3
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Manifest.toml`
  [7073ff75] + IJulia v1.23.3
  [b85f4697] + SoftGlobalScope v1.1.0
  [c2297ded] + ZMQ v1.2.1
  [8f1865be] + ZeroMQ_jll v4.3.4+0
  [a9144af2] + libsodium_jll v1.0.20+0
```

2. Launch a Jupyter session and choose a Julia kernel.

I'm able to launch a Jupyter session. However, when I click new, all my option are Python kernels. I don't see anywhere to launch a Julia kernel.

Has anyone run into a similar problem??

I am running macOS Monterey, version 12.4, Apple M1 Max Chip.

My julia is 1.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Try a different step 2:

```
julia> using IJulia

julia> notebook()
```

This should open Jupyter in a new browser/tab window. Do you see the Julia kernel in this window? (In which case you might just have different Jupyter versions installed on your system).

Answer (score 0):

you're probably using a `jupyter` notebook that didn't come with `IJulia`, thus, you will have to install a kernel spec (a JSON file) so the `jupyter` knows where to find Julia kernel.

Try following:
https://julialang.github.io/IJulia.jl/stable/manual/installation/#Installing-IJulia

More specifically,

> You can force it to use a specific jupyter installation by setting ENV["JUPYTER"] to the path of the jupyter program before running Pkg.build("IJulia")

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the Jupyter notebook you have installed doesn't have IJulia installed. You will have to load IJulia to access Jupyter with a Julia kernel to fix that.

```
julia> using IJulia

julia> notebook()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which was the result of having an older version of Jupyter. I solved it by uninstalling and reinstalling the latest jupyter, then added the R and Julia kernels from thw official R, through R Studio, and Julia sites respectively where each kernel installation did not take more than 2 minutes and all work well.

Good luck
EK