# Has anyone been able to successfully run julia on a Jupyter notebook over ssh?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

I've had so much trouble trying to install Julia and learn how to use it with jupyter over ssh (ssh for reasons that are to complicated to explain). I am unable to even install IJulia without error. I've followed steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306073/cant-run-julia-in-jupyter-notebook) and several other places with no luck. When I initially run `Pkg.add("IJulia")` it's able to install the dependencies but IJulia itself doesn't compile. I try running `Pkg.build("IJulia")` with no issue, but when I open a julia notebook, the kernel never actually runs. When I try to go back to the julia prompt and run `using IJulia`, I get errors like the following:

```
ERROR: LoadError: InitError: SystemError: opening file "[blabla]/mambaforge/envs/jul/share/julia/cert.pem": No such file or directory
```

and

```
ERROR: Failed to precompile IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a] to [blabla]/mambaforge/envs/jul/share/julia/compiled/v1.7/IJulia/jl_yfN9Cx.
```

I've been suffering this for weeks. I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult to get into this language. Has anyone else had issues like this and been able to solve them?

Comment: If you've been struggling with this for weeks, it's definitely time to ask this directly on IJulia's Github page or on Julia Discourse (with a full stacktrace of the second error).

Comment: What do you mean by `use it with jupyter over ssh `? Typical thing is to install IJulia on a remote machine, start a headless Jupyter and set up an SSH tunnel.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Yes, that's exactly what I mean. My issue isn't with the tunneling itself, as it should be the same process as what I do with other work I do with python. I only bring it up in case the possible issue is something nuanced with using a version of jupyter installed with conda instead of the one that comes with IJulia. (neither have worked for me).

Comment: Jupyter works independently of its kernels. Hence you can have one Python running the Jupyter and a completely different Python or Julia running the kernel. From your question I do not know what is the exact configuration that you want to achieve,

Comment: Have you found the answer? If not, if you provide a detailed description on what configuration you exactly want I can make a post on that. Otherwise I would propose to close that question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Ubuntu? I encountered a similar problem in Ubuntu 20.04 recently. I wanted to install IJulia under an anaconda environment but faced the problem that the file `{JULIA_DIR}/share/julia/cert.pem` (in my case, this file has a path of `/home/pc/anaconda3/envs/julia-workspace/share/julia/cert.pem`).

The first reference I find on the internet is [a solution on the julia discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/package-fetch-issues-with-internal-ssl-certificate/43026/2). (Actually there is a mistake in this answer, at least on my operation system, that the file that the symbolic link is created from, is `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` , not `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` )

The problem I faced at this time is that the file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` does not exist! How can it happens? I find [this reference](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html) that guides me to generate the file `ca-certificates.crt` (by the way, you may need `sudo` to run the command `update-ca-certificates`, which updates the directory `/etc/ssl/certs` to hold SSL certificates  and  generates `ca-certificates.crt`)